# Having multiple templates nested within each other using weby

Tags: python, html, templates, web.py, nested

I have set up a website using webpy.
I have my main page called layout.html.  I load foo1.html into layout

```
$def with (content)
<html>
<head>
    <title>Foo</title>
</head>
<body>
$:content
</body>
</html>
```

And the content inside is foo1.html

```
<div> Hello </div>
```

Is it possible to change foo1.html to also load another webpage:

```
$def with (secondarycontent) 
<div> $:secondarycontent </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define `render` as template global

```
template_globals = {}
render_partial = template.render(template_dir, globals=template_globals)
render = template.render(template_dir, globals=template_globals,
                         base='layout')
template_globals.update(render=render_partial)
```

So now you can call it from templates

```
$:render.nested.template()
```